# How to refresh SurfaceView when Activity onResume?

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

I play a rtsp video stream using `MediaPlayer` and display it in a `SurfaceView`. I do MediaPlayer initial works in `Activity.onResume()` and release it in `Activity.onPause()`. It works fine when jump to a **normal** Activity(called `onPause`) then return back(called `onResume`).

The problem is, while video is playing, jump to a **dialog-like** Activity and return back, the video cannot be refreshed(video frame is frozen) but audio was fine. What can I do to play video stream normally in this situation? How to refresh the SurfaceView?

Thank you all.

ps: As description above, **normal Activity** is an Activity that fill up the whole window, and **dialog-like Activity** is an Activity that looks like a AlertDialog, usually an Activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` theme, just like GoogleVoice app. When this kind of Activity is foreground, we can see part of the background Activity.

**EDIT**: My code is a little bit complex, and I paste the key snippet:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //....
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    mHolder = mPreview.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mPath = "rtsp://10.10.20.42/Viral.mp4";
    // Create a new media player and set the listeners
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mPath);
    // mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing to refresh your surface view, might be you are doing some thing wrong with your codes, bdw surface will be destroyed on onPause, better you post the code !!

Comment: @DavidArfin I have pasted the snippet of my code, thanks for your attention. What I want to point out is, it works fine in **normal activity**.

Comment: I guess onPause is not being called in this case and your video activity is loosing the focus once dialog activity popup better you can do it dynamically(i mean release and start it again) as you know when you are going to start Dialog activity and when you are gonna finish it.

Comment: @DavidArfin I have tracked this using logcat already, onPause was called, just the same as a normal Activity push foreground.

Comment: Ok, I will recommend you dnt start media player from onResume method. You can easily track start and finish of dialog activity, once dialog activity finish(onActivityResult) then you can continue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally solved this problem. I did not re set the `SurfaceHolder` of `MediaPlayer`(call `mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(SurfaceHolder holder)`).

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mPath = "rtsp://10.10.20.42/Viral.mp4";
    // Create a new media player and set the listeners
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mPath);
    // mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    if (mHolder != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");
    this.mHolder = surfaceholder;
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceholder);
    }
}
```